# Transpose a length and filter to just a foldr

Tags: haskell

I have this function :

```
count :: Int -> [(Float,Int)] -> Int
count n p = length $ filter ((==n).snd) p
```

and I want to transpose it to a foldr but im having troubles with the lambda function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
count n = foldr (\(f,i) j -> if (i==n) then j+1 else j) 0
```